# Name, title and etc. does not appear using moderncv

Tags: tex-core, moderncv

\name, \title and \social (basically everything before the \begin{document} line) do not appear in my document. I've tried using XeLaTex, LuaLaTex, but it does not affect the output.
My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} 
\social[github]{jdoe}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands like `\name{}`,`\title` and `\social` are preamble commands that wont make visual direct changes to the final document.

Make sure the command `\maketitle` is inside the document environment

Comment: Exactly this. Thanks for the solution